# Skip entering email for registration in web2py

Tags: python, web2py

I'm new to web2py i'm trying to register a user without email address (a reddit style login), but i'm unable skip the email field in auth_user, i did try these because they seemed intuitive

```
 auth.settings.registration_requires_email = False 

 auth.define_tables(username=True, signature=False,email=False)
```

However they don't exist, Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Google Group:

```
def user():
    if request.args(0) == 'register':
        for field in ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email']:
            db.auth_user[field].readable = db.auth_user[field].writable = False
    return dict(form=auth())
```

The above alters the `user()` function in the default.py controller so it simply hides the name and email fields in the registration form (but leaves them visible in the profile form so they can be filled in later if desired).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link I found for [Customizing Auth](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/09/access-control) which explains how to do exactly what you'd like, which is use a username for authentication instead of e-mail address.

> If you add a field called "username", it will be used in place of
>   "email" for login. If you do, you will need to add a validator as
>   well:
>
> `auth_table.username.requires = IS_NOT_IN_DB(db, auth_table.username)`

So it looks you'll have to leverage the *`define_tables()`* function discussed in the link.  Hope this helps!

Comment: This approach is fine if you don't want to record a name or email address at all, but see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23272891/440323) if you simply want to hide those fields during registration (but still allow them to be added in the profile).